# How do I grab only the things I need in D3 v4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, module

I want to build something [like this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/402dd382a51a4f6eea487f9a35566de0) whilst grabbing only the absolute **minimum** necessary from `D3`s now modular library.

So looking at that code, I can see that I need the following (correct me if I'm wrong):

- d3.timeParse in **d3-time-format**
- d3.scaleTime in **d3-scale**
- d3.scaleLinear in **d3-scale**
- d3.line in **d3-shape**
- d3.select in **d3-selection**
- d3.csv in **d3-request**
- d3.extent in **d3-array**
- d3.max in **d3-array**
- d3.axisBottom in **d3-axis**
- d3.axisLeft in **d3-axis**

I then found [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) by Mike himself on how to do the bundling.

I can get this to work, but the stuff that Mike is grabbing is all from the same module `d3-selection`

What do I do when I want to bundle all into one from various modules like in my situation? I am still getting my head around JS Modules! I haven't used those before, but I won't learn until I dive in and do something with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Declare the modules (`d3-array` and so on) as dependencies in your project via npm :

   ```
   npm install --save-dev d3-time-format d3-scale d3-shape d3-selection d3-request d3-array d3-axis
   ```

   Your `package.json` file should now have a `devDependencies` section looking like this

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
       "d3-array": "1.0.1",
       "d3-axis": "1.0.3",
       "d3-request": "1.0.2",
       "d3-scale": "1.0.3",
       "d3-selection": "1.0.2",
       "d3-shape": "1.0.3",
       "d3-time-format": "2.0.2",
       "rollup": "0.36",
       "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2",
       "uglify-js": "2"
   }
   ```
2. Add the relevant [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) in your `index.js` file :

   ```
   export {
       event,
       select,
       selectAll
   } from "d3-selection";

   export {
       timeParse
   } from "d3-time-format";

   export {
       scaleTime,
       scaleLinear
   } from "d3-scale";

   export {
       line
   } from "d3-shape";

   export {
       csv
   } from "d3-request";

   export {
       extent,
       max
   } from "d3-array";

   export {
       axisBottom,
       axisLeft
   } from "d3-axis";
   ```
3. Run the rollup command

   ```
   rollup -c && uglifyjs d3.js -c -m -o d3.min.js
   ```
4. You now have a `d3.max` function available (modified `index.htm`):

   ```
   var y = d3.max([2016, 2017]);
   d3.select("body").append("h1").text("Hello, " + y);
   ```